# auto-commit of offsets Failed & Retry also not working as excepted

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot 2.1.9 with spring Kafka 2.2.9

I am getting some warning in logs file which says commit failed and also i am using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler to capture the error once retry exausted , but sometimes if commits failed its keeps on iterating.

here is my config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaReceiverConfig {

    // Kafka Server Configuration
    @Value("${kafka.servers}")
    private String kafkaServers;

    // Group Identifier
    @Value("${kafka.groupId}")
    private String groupId;

    // Kafka Max Retry Attempts
    @Value("${kafka.retry.maxAttempts:5}")
    private Integer retryMaxAttempts;

    // Kafka Max Retry Interval
    @Value("${kafka.retry.interval:180000}")
    private Long retryInterval;

    // Kafka Concurrency
    @Value("${kafka.concurrency:10}")
    private Integer concurrency;

    // Kafka Concurrency
    @Value("${kafka.poll.timeout:100}")
    private Integer pollTimeout;

    // Kafka Consumer Offset
    @Value("${kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset:earliest}")
    private String offset = "earliest";

    // Logger
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaReceiverConfig.class);

    /**
     * Defines the Max Number of Retry Attempts
     * 
     * @return Return the Retry Policy @see {@link RetryPolicy}
     */
    @Bean
    public RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(retryMaxAttempts);
        return simpleRetryPolicy;
    }

    /**
     * Time before the next Retry can happen, the Time used is in Milliseconds
     * 
     * @return Return the BackOff Policy @see {@link BackOffPolicy}
     */
    @Bean
    public BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryInterval);
        return backOffPolicy;
    }

    /**
     * Get Retry Template
     * 
     * @return Return the Retry Template @see {@link RetryTemplate}
     */
    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
        return retryTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * String Kafka Listener Container Factor
     * 
     * @return @see {@link KafkaListenerContainerFactory}
     */
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String> chainedTM, MessageProducer messageProducer) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedTM);
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        // NOTE: retryMaxAttempts should always +1 due to spring kafka bug
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
            log.warn("failed to process kafka message (retries are exausted). topic name:"+record.topic()+" value:"+record.value());
            messageProducer.saveFailedMessage(record, exception);
        }, retryMaxAttempts + 1);

        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        log.debug("Kafka Receiver Config kafkaListenerContainerFactory created");
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * String Consumer Factory
     * 
     * @return @see {@link ConsumerFactory}
     */
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        log.debug("Kafka Receiver Config consumerFactory created");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    /**
     * Consumer Configurations
     * 
     * @return @see {@link Map}
     */
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        // Disable the Auto Commit if required for testing
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offset);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        log.debug("Kafka Receiver Config consumerConfigs created");
        return props;
    }

}
```

here is log :

```
2019-10-30 15:48:05.907  WARN [xxxxx-component-workflow-starter,,,] 11 --- [nt_create-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=fulfillment_create] Synchronous auto-commit of offsets {fulfillment_create-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=32, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

1. Is there any problem with my config file?
2. how to set max poll and session timeout and all? (give me on example)
3. How to setup SeekToCurrentErrorHandler in spring Kafka 2.2.9 so that it works well (because I cannot upgrade spring Kafka due to some other dependencies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking too long to process the records returned by the poll().

You need to reduce `max.poll.records` (`ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG`) and/or increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

You can't perform a seek after this error - you have lost the partitions.

Comment: default max.poll.records is 500 and  max.poll.interval.ms is 300000 so i am going to change max.poll.records=50 and max.poll.interval.ms=50000. is it fine? or do i need to change any other properties also?

Comment: Is setPollTimeout () method and max.poll.interval.ms is same?

Comment: No. Not at all. Poll timeout is a container property. Poll interval is a kafka consumer property.